# What API is used and not used when DirectX 11 feature level is less than 11_0?

Tags: directx11

Currently, I am programming a DX11 engine using feature level 11_0+.  I am wondering if I wanted to extend support for DX10, and DX9, what else would I have to do differently?

If I make the feature level 9_1, what API calls/shader versions would have to be changed?  Would I still be able to use all of DX11 API?  If not, is there a list of API that is used and not used based on feature level?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: [Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx).

There's quite a bit here and it's not really suitable for copy/pasting into an answer, so you really should go read it yourself.

However, and to summarize, the ID3D11Device and ID3D11DeviceContext interfaces are still used, so it's the D3D11 API that is used, but under lower feature levels certain limits may be smaller and certain API calls, formats, behaviours, etc may be different or not allowed at all.

These are summarized in a table at the linked article.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) for some details on creating devices with a range of feature levels. You may also want to read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) about Direct3D feature levels.